# Random HDD hangs on Debian Stretch

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hangs

I have server with two HDD in RAID1, two SSD in RAID0 and one NVME. But sometimes HDD randomly hangs for couple minutes. Last time HDD not responded for 20 minutes. I have no clue what can be a cause of this problem. I checked data from node exporter and I there is nothing weird. It was at night, so the server was pretty calm. No spikes on CPU usage, memory usage or IOPS.

When this issue occurs, HDD are totally blocked, but I'm not sure with SSDs and the NVME is unaffected for sure. Smart data looks good. I'm not sure if it is a HW or SW problem.

Any ideas where to look for more info?

Thank you.

Debian Strech 4.19.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
Related info from log:

```
INFO: task md0_raid1:248 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
jbd2/dm-17-8    D    0  4937      2 0x80000000
Call Trace:
 ? __schedule+0x3f5/0x880
 schedule+0x32/0x80
 rwsem_down_read_failed+0x12e/0x190
 ? call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x14/0x30
 call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x14/0x30
 down_read+0x1c/0x30
 dm_thin_find_block+0x2e/0x70 [dm_thin_pool]
 thin_map+0x168/0x270 [dm_thin_pool]
 __map_bio+0x42/0x170 [dm_mod]
 __split_and_process_non_flush+0x12c/0x220 [dm_mod]
 ? __process_bio+0x170/0x170 [dm_mod]
 __split_and_process_bio+0xb2/0x1a0 [dm_mod]
 __dm_make_request.isra.31+0x3f/0xa0 [dm_mod]
 generic_make_request+0x1e7/0x410
 ? submit_bio+0x6c/0x140
 submit_bio+0x6c/0x140
 ? guard_bio_eod+0x36/0x100
 submit_bh_wbc+0x163/0x190
 ? jbd2_journal_begin_ordered_truncate+0xa0/0xa0 [jbd2]
 jbd2_journal_commit_transaction+0x5ec/0x18a0 [jbd2]
 ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
 ? __switch_to_asm+0x34/0x70
 ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
 ? kjournald2+0xc1/0x260 [jbd2]
 kjournald2+0xc1/0x260 [jbd2]
 ? remove_wait_queue+0x60/0x60
 kthread+0xf8/0x130
 ? commit_timeout+0x10/0x10 [jbd2]
 ? kthread_create_worker_on_cpu+0x70/0x70
 ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
INFO: task rs:main Q:Reg:5075 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Not tainted 4.19.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.12-1~bpo9+1
 ? alloc_set_pte+0x3f8/0x5b0
 __do_page_fault+0x255/0x4f0
RAX: 00007f6d6e592638 RBX: 00007fff92429f80 RCX: 00007f6d6e4e57c0
```

Smart data

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Re
Device Model:     WDC WD2004FBYZ-01YCBB1
[...]

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 216) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   182   182   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3866
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       62
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   100   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   058   058   000    Old_age   Always       -       31119
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       62
 16 Unknown_Attribute       0x0022   007   193   000    Old_age   Always       -       390630975468
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       42
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       86
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   119   104   000    Old_age   Always       -       28
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     29834         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Re
Device Model:     WDC WD2004FBYZ-01YCBB1
[...]

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 216) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   180   180   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3991
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       62
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   058   058   000    Old_age   Always       -       31118
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       62
 16 Unknown_Attribute       0x0022   006   194   000    Old_age   Always       -       370886226476
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       42
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       81
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   116   106   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     29833         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     INTEL SSDSC2KG480G8
[...]

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   72) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x79) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9754
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       21474773638
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   090    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   070   066   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 17/36)
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       30
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
225 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       25630
226 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       61
227 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       69
228 Power-off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       585288
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
234 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       21474773638
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       25630
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       58487
243 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       132255

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      9516         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     INTEL SSDSC2KG480G8
[...]

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   72) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x79) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9754
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       42949609951
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   090    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   069   065   000    Old_age   Always       -       31 (Min/Max 17/36)
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
225 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       25308
226 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       61
227 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       69
228 Power-off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       585269
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
234 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       42949609951
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       25308
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       58473
243 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       133623

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      9516         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Where is the SMART data? This should have been included in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused by NFS server (long-term reported bug) in container/VPS (not matter if is in container or VPS). When you mount NFS to physical host from container or VPS on the same physical host and your server get some stress, NFS server can hang (and this will be extended to other processes).

In this case it was caused by memory "stress". The server had 50% used by applications and almost 50% used by file cache (so not really loaded server).

Mount NFS in container from another container on the same host is ok.